# Titlesec, runin shape and amsthm

Tags: numbering, titlesec, amsthm

I'm trying to have an *old fashioned* style of (sub)section numbering as in EGA (*Eléments de Géométrie Algébrique*, by A.Grothendieck and J.Dieudonné). For a LaTeX written example, see [here](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~ducros/Outils-geoalg.pdf).

I did it with the use of the **titlesec** package, and the following problem arrises : if a section has the shape **runin** and an amsthm environment follows immediately, the environment creates a line break as usual, which I do not want.

Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize\bfseries}{(\thesubsection)}{5pt}{}

\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{}
\begin{thm}
  Foo bar.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the line break after **(1.1)** to begin the *thm* environment : I would like **Theorem** to be right after **(1.1)** on the same line.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The style is *really* old fashioned. `;-)`

Define `thm` to share the `subsection` counter and modify how the theorem headers are printed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\thmhead#1#2#3{%
  (\thmnumber{\@upn{#2})\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }}%
  \thmname{#1}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont(#3)}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize\bfseries}{(\thesubsection)}{5pt}{}

\newtheorem{thm}[subsection]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

Some introductory text.

\subsection{}
A subsection

\begin{thm}
  Foo bar.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Someone]
  Foo bar.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [dieudonne](https://github.com/jonsterling/latex-dieudonne) package does exactly what you want.
The [demo file](https://github.com/jonsterling/latex-dieudonne/blob/main/main.tex) requires [garamondx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366322/34551) and gives:

[image]