# Problem with babel [brazil] and tikz-cd's phantom arrows

Tags: babel, tikz-cd

I'm trying to draw the following diagram using tikz-cd

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, tikz-cd}
\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
0 \ar{r} & L' \ar{r}{j} \ar[equal]{d} & E' \times_{B'} B \ar{d}[swap]{p_1} \ar{r}{p_2} \ar[dr, phantom, "\square"] & B \ar{r} \ar{d}{v} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & L' \ar{r}[swap]{j'} & E' \ar{r}[swap]{f'} & B' \ar{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

Everything goes fine until I load `babel` package. The problem is specifically with the phantom option. I've tried solutions for similar problems, but none of them worked. Would it be possible to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a variant problem of [Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={
    execute at begin picture={\shorthandoff{"}},
    execute at end picture={\shorthandon{"}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
0 \ar{r} &
  L' \ar{r}{j} \ar[equal]{d} &
  E' \times_{B'} B \ar{d}[swap]{p_1} \ar{r}{p_2} \ar[dr, phantom, "\square"] & 
  B \ar{r} \ar{d}{v} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & L' \ar{r}[swap]{j'} & E' \ar{r}[swap]{f'} & B' \ar{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is because the `brazil` option makes `"` into a shorthand character that confuses TikZ. I don't think you need the `commutative diagrams/.cd` option.

Comment: Thanks egreg, this solved the problem. The superfluous bit of code appeared because I use the stealth style for arrows and did not remove everything needed for it. By the way, do you know why `\ar{dr}[phantom]{\square}` doesn't work? Also let me take the opportunity to thank you for your answers here, specially the one for this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140490/titlesec-runin-shape-and-amsthm).

Comment: And `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` doesn't work in this case. May be a bug in `babel` library.

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, I tried it and it fails.