# How to get Garamondx working?

Tags: garamondx

I am using Texmaker with TeXLive on Windows 10. I want to use some type of 'Garamond' font for my math paper.

Looking around I found the fonts GaramondNo8 and Garamondx can be used to provide nice looking text and mathematics.

I am having a lot of difficulty getting them to work. First, when I try to use

```
\usepackage{garamondx}
```

I get the the error message: File 'garamondx.sty' not found. Looking online in find this is because of some restriction on those fonts and that I need to use getnonfreefonts (http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/). When I download the installer, it asks me what program to use to run it. I don't know what program to run it with, its file type is "file".

Basically, I want to know what code I need to put in my LaTeX file to use these fonts and how to get them installed.

Sorry...I am a complete noob and can't figure any of this out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to install it with TeX Live Package Manager?

Comment: I'm not sure what TeX Live Package Manager. I installed TexLive then changed PATH with some help of another forum. I just downloaded the getnonfreefonts installer form that website.

Comment: I've just posted an explanation on how to do it (under MiKTeX, but most of the procedure should be the same with TeX Live).

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be the same as for MiKTeX: I've checked it's not in any distribution. You can easily install it by hand; download the ready-to-install `garamondx.tds.zip` from the [install/fonts](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/install/fonts) directory on CTAN, and unzip it *at the root* of your `texmf-local` directory.

(This is the procedure for MiKTeX – it may slightly differ for TeX Live). In some subdirectory  of `texmf-local` (or in your home directory) you should have an  `updmap.cfg` file, in which you can add this line:

```
Map zgm.map
```

In MiKTeX, there remains a last step (not sure it is required under TeX Live): run from the command line, as administrator: `updmap.exe`. This is to refresh the type1 fonts databases, so the compiler knows where to find the font files.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that OP was not familiar with scripts and Unix systems. The simplest way is indeed to use [getnonfreefonts](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/):

1. Download the script, at https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
2. In the folder where you downloaded it, run `chmod +x install-getnonfreefonts`
3. Become super-user / admin
4. Type `./install-getnonfreefonts` or `texlua install-getnonfreefonts`
5. Type `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/getnonfreefonts --sys garamondx` or something similar.

That's it!

Comment: In the last step, I needed to do `sudo /usr/.../getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl --sys garamondx`. The necessity of `sudo` is explained here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422623/installing-getnonfreefonts-mactex).